# boot.log.1 question if this is of concern or not

Tags: boot

I am only asking to allay any unfounded fears.

I was checking my `/var/log/boot.log.1` file.

This is part of it.

```
    ------------ Sat Jul 01 13:31:29 AEST 2023 ------------
[  OK  ] Finished Uncomplicated firewall.
[  OK  ] Finished Clean up any mess left by 0dns-up.
[  OK  ] Started Show Plymouth Boot Screen.
[  OK  ] Started Forward Password R…s to Plymouth Directory Watch.
[  OK  ] Reached target Local Encrypted Volumes.
         Mounting Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System...
[  OK  ] Started Nameserver information manager.
[  OK  ] Reached target Preparation for Network.
[  OK  ] Finished Create Volatile Files and Directories.
         Mounting RPC Pipe File System...
         Starting Load Kernel Module chromeos_pstore...
         Starting Load Kernel Module efi_pstore...
         Starting Load Kernel Module pstore_blk...
         Starting Load Kernel Module pstore_zone...
         Starting Load Kernel Module ramoops...
         Starting RPC bind portmap service...
         Starting Network Name Resolution...
         Starting Record System Boot/Shutdown in UTMP...
[  OK  ] Started RPC bind portmap service.
```

These two lines in particular.

```
Reached target Local Encrypted Volumes.
         Mounting Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System...
```

Should I be worried?

Comment: Did you install binfmt or related packages?

Comment: No I haven't.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message you flagged is harmless, merely informing you that the `binfmt_misc` system has been activated.

This system provides a way to describe to the kernel how to recognize any arbitrary executable file format and tell it what interpreter is used to run that file.

Unix has always had this feature built in, but traditionally, it only recognizes native binary executables and text script files with a line starting with `#!/path/to/interpreter`.  The binfmt misc system allows adding additional magic numbers and interpreters that use arbitrary formats.  For example, this can allow it to recognize java binaries and run them the same way (syntactically) you would run normal executables.

For more information, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binfmt_misc